# How to write a drop-in replacements for fundamental type (float) that override operator== in C++?

Tags: c++

We can not compare binary floating point directly. 
I am writting a drop-in replacements class for float 
which override the bulti-in compare operators::

```
template<class U>
class Float {
    private:
        U val;
    public:
        Float(U v = 0): val(v) {}
        operator U() const { return val; }

        friend bool operator<(Float a, Float b) { return a.val + 1e-6 < b.val; }
        friend bool operator==(Float a, Float b) { return !(a < b) && !(b < a); }

        friend Float operator*(Float a, Float b) { return a.val * b.val; }
        template<class T>
        friend Float operator*(T a, Float b) { return a * b.val; }
        template<class T>
        friend Float operator*(Float a, T b) { return a.val * b; }
};
```

Now we can write something like this::

```
#include<assert.h>
int main() {
    Float<double> a = 0.2, b = 0.02;
    assert(a * a == 2 * b);
}
```

However, this code will show a unexpected behavior::

```
#include<complex>
int main() {
    std::complex< Float<double> > a(0.2);
    a * 2.0;
}
```

It will call `Float::operator*(std::complex<Float<double> >, Float)` again and again 
like a recursive endless loop, and finally get stack overflow.
How to fix this?

**Edit**

DeadMG and Charles Bailey point out that From ISO/IEC 14882:2011, 26.4: "The effect of instantiating the template complex for any type other than float, double, or long double is unspecified."

Maybe I have given a wrong counter example. We could still discuss how to write a good drop-in replacements class for fundamental type.

Let me clear my motivation, `assert(0.1 * 0.1 == 0.01);` is counterintuitive. That is why I write a Float class which used "almost equal" behavior to compare two floating number.

Comment: You usually want only *one* `operator*`, defined as a global overload, taking your type for both operands (and using the conversion constructor as needed). `friend operator *(Float const &a, Float const &b) { return a.val * b.val; }`.

Comment: It is UB to instantiate `std::complex` with anything except `float` or `double` or `long double`, IIRC.

Comment: @DeadMG, Yes, that seems right.

Comment: @DeadMG: Technically only unspecified, but yeah, still not portable.

Comment: @DeadMG, Wow, news to me.  Haven't used std::complex much..

Comment: @DeadMG, [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/complex/) "complex is specialized for the three fundamental floating-point types: float, double and long double.These specializations have the same members as the template, but optimize its implementation for these fundamental types, as well as they allow operations with other instantiations of complex (complex objects with different template argument)."

Comment: What exactly do you plan to do with your `==` and `<`? Your equality operator does not define an equivalence relation and your "less than" operator doesn't define a strict weak order. It is misleading, IMHO, to call them `==` and `<`; they would be better as named free functions which would make your wrapper class redundant.

Comment: @ytj: The info from your link is wrong.  Despite the name, cplusplus.com is not a definitive source for C++ info.

Comment: @ytj: From ISO/IEC 14882:2011, 26.4: "The effect of instantiating the template `complex` for any type other than `float`, `double`, or `long double` is unspecified."

Answer (score 2):

Make your constructor explicit.

```
a * 2.0;
```

Is implicitly constructing a Float, then calling:

```
template<class T>
friend Float operator*(T a, Float b) 
{
    return a * b.val;
}
```

Which is in turn implicitly constructing another Float when you invoke the * operator on b.val;  And you recurse on from there.

You will need to flesh out your expected behaviors some more before I could suggest a complete fix.

The code I used to explore it & test a fix:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class U>
class Float {
    private:
        U val;
    public:
        explicit Float(U v = 0): val(v) 
        {
            std::cout << "constructor ";
        }
        operator U() const { return val; }

        friend bool operator<(Float a, Float b) { return a.val + 1e-6 < b.val; }
        friend bool operator==(Float a, Float b) { return !(a < b) && !(b < a); }

        friend Float operator*(Float a, Float b) { return a.val * b.val; }
    template<class T>
    friend Float operator*(T a, Float b) 
    {
        std::cout << "here";
        return a * b.val;
     }

        template<class T>
        friend Float operator*(Float a, T b) { return a.val * b; }
};

#include<complex>
int main() {
    std::complex< Float<double> > a(0.2);
    a * 2.0;
}
```

Comment: remove 'explicit' to make it compile.